# Math blog directory

Tags: big-list

Does anyone have a list of high quality mathematics (or related) blogs. I am of course aware of Terry Tao's most excellent blog, and also of ldtopology.wordpress.com, but I am sure the complete list is far longer.

**EDIT** As I say in my comment, the key point is that I am looking for *high quality* blogs. nLab and mathblogging both give a VERY long list, and while they are both useful resources (neither of which I was aware of before asking the question) neither is sufficiently selective to be really useful.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is already a question about this. It has surely been discussed in meta, and there is http://www.mathblogging.org/ which is probably the information should be anyways!

Comment: Did you try googling? There is a list, with recommendations and other such goodies: http://www.mathblogging.org/ I am voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: The key word is "high quality". As for it being off-topic, I disagree completely, and as for Mariano's theory, I did check before asking. @Felipe: if mathblogging.org has some editorial content, yours is obviously the answer I was looking for...


Comment: In view of the edit, vote to close as subjective.  

Comment: @quid: vote all you want, but some blogs are done by graduate students trying to understand basic things, with which there is nothing wrong, it's just not very interesting to me or other people who could loosely be described as professionals. If you look at the suggested sources, (nLab and mathblogging), you will see what I mean -- there are literally hundreds of blogs, and life is too short to sift through all of them. Everything I every saw on Terry Tao's blog is extremely enlightening, so there is some hope that something might be at least in the same league.

Comment: @Igor Rivin: look, first you did not even say what you mean with high quality. Now, it seems it is sort of about lot of advanced mathmatics (well presented). This is already more precise, but not synonymous with high quality, IMO. High quality is simply a most vague/subjective term, sure *you* know what *you* meant. And,  in addition, it could cause unfortunate situations if somebody where to name a blog as high quality you consider as 'not very interesting'. Or just look at a comment you already made under one answer. Obviously, it is not absurd to describe/categorize/rate blogs...

Comment: ...but then first you should specifify the criteria beyond simply 'high quality' and second it would still be to subjective and possibly argumentative for MO. 

Comment: Mathblogging has "Our weekly picks", which often points at particularly high quality blogs. http://www.mathblogging.org/

Comment: @Joel: yes, I saw that, but it was not very satisfying (maybe because their definition of "math" is a little broad; a lot of their picks concern policy or education, or?!

Comment: I agree that "high quality" is subjective. I'd like to add that blogging is also a kind of communicationa dn hence, works in two ways. Thus, a general advice in finding blogs is to write one yourself and take active part in the "blogoshpere" by reading, reblogging and commenting other blogs.

Comment: I've voted to close, since this question is attracting answers that are clearly out of scope of what the OP wanted. Anyone who wants to argue for reopening, start a meta thread.

Comment: https://blogs.ams.org/blogonmathblogs/ blog on math blogs, http://rankedblogs.com/math and old one: http://blogmetrics.org/math

Comment: https://blogs.ams.org several blogs hosted by AMS

Comment: https://blog.feedspot.com/math_blogs/ 100 blogs with teaching incline

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-of-the-best-Mathematics-blogs

Comment: http://www.mastersincomputerscience.net/top-50-computer-science-blogs.html computer science blogs

Answer (score 5):

There's this nLab page: http://www.ncatlab.org/nlab/show/math+blogs and some other lists that it links to.

Answer (score 3):

[Jonathan Borwein](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/jonathan-m-borwein), [Tim Chartier](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/tim-chartier), [Keith Devlin](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/dr-keith-devlin), and [Frank Morgan](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/frank-morgan) are now all blogging for the Huffington Post.

Comment: The words "high quality" and "Huffington post" do not seem to be friends.

Comment: @Igor: That's my general impression too, but I'm actually impressed that they decided to hire math bloggers and that they chose well.

Answer (score 3):

I read [Shuyun Wu](http://conan777.wordpress.com/)'s and [Danny Calegari](http://lamington.wordpress.com/)'s blogs occasionally, as a rising graduate student they are "high quality" for me...

I would add a few blogs I seldom read like [Zachery Abel](http://blog.zacharyabel.com/)'s, [Gil Kalai](http://gilkalai.wordpress.com/)'s, etc. Generally you can "discover" a wide range of math blogs simply by following links in anyone of them...

Answer (score 2):

John Roe had a nice blog http://www.math.psu.edu/roe/ for things in non commutative geometry and else too ; but unfortunately, it's not up to date (you can still probably find good stuffs)

Comment: Oh and yeah, I forgot the canonical blog for ncg: http://noncommutativegeometry.blogspot.com/
Good for positions advertisement too, and reach other blogs.

Comment: John Roe's term as department head just ended and he'll be on sabbatical next year, so there is hope that his blogging will resume.

Comment: That's a very good news ! 